# Probability and Probability Distributions

Tags: statistics

I have a question i need to answer in my assignment.

Question
The machine repair department of Scorpio Press receives an average of 2 calls for service per hour. What is the probability of receiving no service calls in a 45 minute period?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We can be more helpful if you show us what you have been done already.

Comment: Aside from showing what you have tried, it's important to state what assumptions you are making.  If, say, one call comes in like clockwork, every $30$ minutes then the answer is $0$.  Presumably, though,  you mean to assume something like a Poisson process here, but it should be spelled out.

Comment: No answer to the question from Vasily Mich one hour later... Does it mean that you are hard working on this problem, or are you awaiting a "ready-to-eat" answer from us ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems reasonable to assume that repair requests arrive according to a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda = 2.$ The rate per 45.min or 3/4 of an hour is $\lambda^\prime = 1.5.$ So you have $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(1.5)$
 and you seek $P(X = 0).$

In R statistical software, this is computed as follows, where `dpois` is a Poisson PDF:

```
dpois(0, 1.5)
[1] 0.2231302
```

I will leave it to you to look at the formula for the Poisson PDF and show how to compute the answer for your assignment.